# No se ejecuta el codigo de IValidatableObject ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validación

Tengo un Model, el cual utiliza diversas anotations (Required, RegularExpression, Remote, etc) para ser ejecutadas en el lado del cliente. Pero, en caso de que el usuario deshabilite el código javascript en el Navegador, he intentado realizar una validación extra en el lado del servidor, mediante la interfaz `IValidatableObject`.

El problema es que cuando hago un debug de la app, el código del metodo `Validate` (que implementa la interfaz `IValidatableObject` sencillamente NO SE EJECUTA), es como si no existiera. He puesto uun punto de interrupción para comprobarlo... y nada!!!

Este es el código del Model:

```
public partial class ModelX : IValidatableObject
{
    [Key]
    public int Id_X { get; set; }
    public string Campo1 { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required.")]
    public string Campo2 { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    List<ValidationResult> err = new List<ValidationResult>();
    Clase claseX = new ClaseX();

    if (ClaseX.MetodoControladorError("Campo2"))
    {
        err.Add(new ValidationResult("Error", new string[] { "Campo2" }));
    }

    return err;
}
```

Este es el código del Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var model = db.VW_OPERAZIONE_L1.Find(id);
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(ModelX model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.TB_X.Add(model);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Action", "Controller");
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Este es el código de la vista:

```
@model ModeloX
@{
    ViewBag.Title = Título...
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id_X)

    <div class="form-group">
         @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Campo1)
         @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Campo1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Campo1, "", new { @class = "error" })
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
         @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Campo2)
         @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Campo2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Campo2, "", new { @class = "error" })
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

¿QUÉ OPINAN QUE PUEDA ESTAR SUCEDIENDO?

Muchas Gracias,
Angel

Answer (score 0):

Debes tener en cuenta que cuando haces que tu Modelo `ModelX` implemente la Interfaz `IValidatableObject`, el método `Validate` de la interfaz debe de ir **dentro de la Clase** de Modelo, y tu lo tienes fuera:

```
public partial class ModelX : IValidatableObject
{
    [Key]
    public int Id_X { get; set; }
    public string Campo1 { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required.")]
    public string Campo2 { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
          List<ValidationResult> err = new List<ValidationResult>();
          Clase claseX = new ClaseX();

          if (ClaseX.MetodoControladorError("Campo2"))
          {
             err.Add(new ValidationResult("Error", new string[] { "Campo2" }));
          }

         return err;
     }
}
```